# UnsupportedOperationException when add item to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, null, unsupportedoperation

I have the below class which contains a list of bankAccounts. I have another traitement where I add many BankAccounts to a specific AssignmentIban with the `addBankAccount` method. But the problem I have this error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null`

```
public class AssignmentIban  {

    private List<BankAccount> bankAccounts;

    public void addBankAccount(BankAccount bankAccount) {
        if (this.bankAccounts== null || this.bankAccounts.isEmpty()) {
            this.bankAccounts= new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.bankAccounts.add(bankAccount); // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    }

}
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
> at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
> at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
> at com.test.AssignmentIban.addBankAccount(AssignmentIban.java:20)

Comment: Is it possible that bankAccounts is already initialized to a List instance that does not support adding? If not, why don't you initialize `bankAccounts` in the declaration?

`private List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: `this` is redundant

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get, including the stacktrace. If possible, add a [mcve].

Comment: Even stronger, a [mre] is required for this case.

Comment: Could you please add code which you execute when you get this error? The code (or some test, probably) where you call `addBankAccount`?

Comment: Check the code which is calling addBankAccount method. May be it is passing immutable list to this method

Answer (score 2):

Probably the list is an immutable list, for example is obtained with [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) method:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array

In this case the implementation doesn't support method to modify the list and every temptative to invoke a method to modify the list generates an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) is dedicated to the Collection framework to signal exactly this beahaviour:

> **Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported**.
> This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework.